# Как растянуть изображение по ширине экрана если его ограничивает родительская ширина и так же разместить его по центру

Tags: html, css

Есть блок с классом `container` который ограничивает контент своим размером, так же размещая его по центру

```css
.container{
      width:300px;
      margin-right:auto;
      margin-left:auto;
}
.offer__content{
      background:url("https://krot.info/uploads/posts/2020-01/1579418974_1-2.jpg");
      background-size:contain;
}
```

```html
<section class="offer ">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="offer__content">
              <div class="offer__info">
                контент </br>
            контент </br>
            контент </br>
            контент </br>
              </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Как видно на примере, изображение входит в `container` тем самым ограничивается, что можно сделать чтоб изображение не зависело от ограничений в ширине `container`, но чтоб тоже располагался по центру при уменьшение размера странички. Возможно я не верно думаю на счет этого, хотелось бы узнать в таком случае как было бы вернее, спасибо

Comment: А к offer нельзя сделать background ? И использовать background-position

Comment: Ответ был так прост...до этого момента я не знал о background-position, по этому мучился

Comment: Впереди еще много интересного, удачи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

чтобы изображение не зависило от контейнера, можно разместить выше, например в секшин:
section{
background:url("https://krot.info/uploads/posts/2020-01/1579418974_1-2.jpg") center center no-repeat;
}